# Plot Trimesh object like with Axes3D.plot_trisurf()

Tags: python, 3d, mplot3d, trimesh

I have a Trimesh object and I can't figure out how to plot it. My goal is something like the Axes3D.plot_trisurf() function from mplot3d would produce (see below). The Trimesh object even has an attribute containing the faces, but I don't know where to get the coordinates of the grid points.

Thanks for any idea!

[image: trisurf plot from mplot3d]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do this, where `mesh` is your Trimesh object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(mesh.vertices[:, 0], mesh.vertices[:,1], triangles=mesh.faces, Z=mesh.vertices[:,2]) 
plt.show()
```

[image: messy trimesh plotted with plot_trisurf]

You may have to play with the scale, aspect, rotation, etc.